# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity problems when using existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am running into authentication problems when setting LazyLoadingEnabled=false and ProxyCreationEnabled=false. Is Asp.net Identity framework not loading their related data manually and if not should they?

Comment: It would be better if you can update your question with more information. I assume you are use use EntityFramework (if yes, please Tag, so the question is transparent to a wider audience). Also what exactly the authentication issues/errors you encounter? Any code samples that might assist reader would help. This way it is likely you get a more precise/complete answer.

Comment: I have come across this as well seems as the user must log in twice  or else the related user tables ie roles which sends you back to the log on screen are not loaded. This occurs only when Lazy loading is set to off. I would like to know why this occurs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Back in EF4 there was a misunderstading or missnaming in the lazyLoadingEnabled properties of the context. May be it is the sae in this newer version.

You can easily think that LazyLoadingEnabled set in false indicates an eager loading, but not. I think it may be a bug or perhaps the developer behind this got his head confused.

the lazyness is not of the ORM but of you as developer. True indicates you are lazy and you want the ORM to load navigation properties for you; false indicates you are not lazy and want to load them on demand each time you want.

For further explanation you can read this post, it is in spanish but is quite easy. http://rickersilva.net/?p=123